# I want to use my phone to connect view web apps in my ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

But I got Forbidden page when accessing for example 192.168.1.108

The address is correct.

How do I allow access?

Comment: 2 poorly written sentences and 1 5 word question. With a post like that the only answer your going to get is RTFM. Or you could add all the missing details.

Answer (score 0):

First, find out your ip address:

```
ifconfig
```

This is used to find out the server's ip address.

Have nmap installed on server (sudo apt-get install nmap on linux), then to find out all ip addresses within the network run this:

```
sudo nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

Update apache configuration to make sure connection is allowed:
vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
find the part where it says something like:

```
    <Directory /media/jay/Data/apache/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1
            Allow from ::1
            Allow from localhost
    </Directory>
```

Then add:
Allow from [ip of mobile device]

Try connecting to server from mobile device.

To check if connected properly, run this command on server:
sudo tcpdump -i any -vvv -s 1600 port 80
then from client try to connect to that server to see packets received.